# Fatal Runtime Error - C Functions

Tags: c, arrays, fatal-error

I am trying to create a function that capitalises all chars in an array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void capitaliser(char inputText[])
{
    int counter;
   char upperLetter;
   char lowerLetter;

   for (counter = 0; counter < 26; counter++)
   {
      lowerLetter = 'a';

    for (char upperLetter = 'A'; upperLetter <= 'Z'; upperLetter++)
      {
         if(inputText[counter] == lowerLetter)
            inputText[counter] = upperLetter;

            lowerLetter++;
      }
   }
}


int main( void )
{
   int counter;
   char array1[26]; = {'\0'};
   char array2[26]; = {'\0'};       

   scanf("%s %s", array1, array2);      

   capitaliser(array1[26]);
   capitaliser(array2[26]);

   for ( counter = 0; counter < 26; counter++ )
   {
      printf("\n%c %c", array1[counter], array2[counter]);
   }
}
```

When the code from the function is placed in main and 'inputText' is replaced with either 'array1' or 'array2' the program runs fine and gives the desired outputs. However, when I try to run the code as a function I am greeted by 'Fatal Runtime Error'.

From this I assume that I am setting up the function incorrectly. Am I missing something incredibly obvious?

Comment: I've been using 2 words separated by a space i.e. 'smelly cheese'. If I comment out the functions within main then the program runs and outputs the words 1 char at a time

Comment: What is this syntax: `char array1[26]; = {'\0'};` ??? Does it compile at all?

Answer (score 2):

In the expression

```
capitaliser(array1[26])
```

`array[26]` passes the *twenty-seventh* element of the array `array1` to the function, converted to a pointer. First of all, your index is out of bounds of the array, secondly passing a single character converted to a pointer will not pass a valid pointer.

You want e.g.

```
capitaliser(array1)
```

Note the lack of indexing.

Answer (score 0):

you are referring to a location which is you are not supposed to. 
`array1[26]` actually does not exists. `int array1[length]` is an array of size length whose index starts from `0` and end with `length-1`.

The way you are passing the array is inappropriate, this way you will be sending only one value to the function and the function definition is bound to receive an array, this also leads to an error.

The better way to send an array is `<functionName>(array1)`, where array1 being my array variable.